# Wordpress - Get Custom Field Value in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

In wordpress is there any way that I can get the value of a custom field in jQuery?

Comment: I don't see how WordPress and jQuery correlates here. What field do you mean? HTML Form field?

Comment: I just realised that they must be stored somewhere in the wordpress database... I think this is more of a wordpress question rather than jQuery question. It would be great if these could be written to the page as a hidden form field.

Answer (score 3):

this should do the trick:

```
function my_jquery_var() {
    global $post;
    if ( $my_custom_field_name = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_custom_field_name', 1 ) ) { 
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">var my_custom_field_name = "' . $my_custom_field_name . '";</script>' . "\n";
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_jquery_var' );
```

it hooks into the wordpress head, checks to see if the current post or page has a custom field called my_custom_field_name, if it does it spits out a var in java script that can then be used by jquery anywhere else.

It's tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

Custom field values are stored in your database, therefore, you can't access them via jQuery unless you've made it available to the resulting HTML markup somehow.

If you're thinking of using custom field values in your jQuery/JS, I'd go about it by modifying my theme to actually spout the values I need directly on the markup. You could use hidden `INPUT` fields for that, or maybe even flushing the values directly on some script.